# How duplicate order automatically with commerce 2

Tags: commerce, rules, views

How do I automatically duplicate an order?
I use Drupal 8 and Drupal Commerce 2. I need to duplicate some orders, each week, automatically.

Orders have a Boolean field (recurrent_order). When the field is filled, the web site has to create the same order at the end of the week.

I have achieved this with rules and VBO on Drupal 7: On maintenance task, a rule finds an array filled by a VBO view, and a component duplicates the content.

In Drupal 8 there isn't VBO view access from a rule.

How can I achieve this? Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for duplicate order with a cron job:

```
function commande_et_paiement_cron() {
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', 'abonnement');
$query->condition('field_livraison', 3);//livraison le vendredi
$entity_ids = $query->execute();


foreach ($entity_ids as $entity_id) {
$abo = Node::load($entity_id);

//utilisateur
$user = $abo->get('field_utilisateur')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
$utilisateur = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user);


//profile
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$profile = $entity_manager->getStorage('profile')->load($user);  


//abonnement
$nid= $abo->id();

//livraison
$date_livraison = new DateTime();
$date_livraison->modify('next friday');



//ligne de commande
$line_items = array();
$abo_array= $abo->get('field_abo_produits')->getValue();

foreach ($abo_array as $abo_item) {
    $ligne = $abo_item['target_id'];        
    //load produit abonnement      
    $item = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem::load($ligne);
    $quantite = $item->getQuantity();
    $produit = $item->getPurchasedEntity();


    $order_item = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem::create([
    'type' => 'default',
    'purchased_entity' => $produit,
    'quantity' => $quantite,
    //'unit_price' => $role_price,
    ]);

    $order_item->save();        
    array_push($line_items,$order_item);        
    }

//creation de la commande
$order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::create([
      'type' => 'default',
      'store_id' => 1,
      'checkout_flow' => 'boulangerie',      
      'uid' => $user,
      'billing_profile' =>$profile,
      'field_abonnement' => $nid,
      'placed' => time(),
      'field_date_livraison' =>$date_livraison->format('Y-m-d'),
      'order_items' =>$line_items,
      'state' => 'draft'
    //'completed' => time(),

    ]);        
    $order->save(); 
    $order->set('order_number', $order->id()); 
    $order->save(); 
    $order->set('state', 'complete');
    /*$comment = 'blabla';
     $logStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_log');        
    $logStorage->generate($order, 'order_comment', ['comment' => $comment])->save();      */
    $order->save();
   }        
}
```